# Htaccess not working on Mamp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm a french guy so excuse my bad english :(

So, in my company I develop a website (PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript, MySQL, JQuery) , and it is almost finished. I'm trying to fix security issues, like the parameters in the URL.
First my project : [Project Organisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjD83.jpg)
As u can see, i'm working with my own organization "MVC". But that's not the point. 
The main file is Blog.php at the root. This is in this file that i'm doing all my redirections with the URL.

For Example, to go to the admin space, i'm sending :

`<a href="blog.php?action=adminSpace&id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ; ?>"> Admin Space</a>`

and in blog.php I get :

`if($_GET['action'] == 'adminSpace')
 {
     include_once('vue/adminSpace.php');
 }`

And for every links that's the same. I Often send an ID too, to get further informations, so my URL often looks like this :

`http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/blog.php?action=adminSpace&id=3`

I'd like having nice URLs like :

`http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/blog.php/adminSpace/3`

See what i mean ??? :p

I'm on MAC Os Sierra, and i've changed my Httpd.conf file, to change the AllowOverride None to All, and to check if the `mod_rewrite.so` is activated. My files is named `.htaccess` in the root of the project.

The content of my .htaccess file :

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^blog.php/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)/(\d+) blog.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L]`

I'm sorry for the long post guys :p I hope u have understood my problem :)

EDIT : The rule i've written doesn't work after many tries, but when i'm writting weird stuffs like `RewriteEngineriing Off RuleRewrite` my website redirect me to an 500 internal server error. So That means that my htaccess Works :/

I guess this is my RewriteRule :( 
Love u all and thx for helping

Comment: Which folder is your .htaccess located?

Comment: Why are you checking for `^blog.php/…` in your RewriteRule, when as you said the URL you want to use is `http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/adminSpace/3`?

Comment: That's my bad, i wrote it bad, i'll change this man :) Ty

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in `sos_informatique/.htaccess` on my server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^blog.php/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)/(\d+) blog.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It actually works in converting `http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/blog.php/articleType/123` requests into `http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/blog.php?action=actionType&id=123`.

Please note that the `actionType` part must be consists of only alphabet (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), `-`, `_` and `.`.

Comment: Hi Koala, ty for ur answer. I tried this but it doesn't work.                                   My Urls are like : `http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/blog.php?action=articleLaptop&id=1` and i'd like :  `http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/blog.php/articleLaptop/1` do u see what i mean ?

Comment: I think I mis-read your requirement. My .htaccess work for path `localhost:8888/sos_informatique/abc/123`

Comment: Strange thing is that I tried your version of `.htaccess` on my Apache, it works for path `http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/blog.php/articleLapto‌​p/1`

Comment: That's weird .. On a french forum a guy helped me and found the solution, but on my code it doesn't work :( Do u think it's a problem about MAMP ?

Comment: One more wierd thing. If I copy the URL path from your comments to my browser, the path becomes `http://localhost:8888/sos_informatique/blog.php/articleLapto%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bp/1`. Could that be some invisible garbage code in your URL?

Comment: I just tried it, and ur right, on Safari the url looks like u wrote it :/ Ok i'll check this out. Ty man, i'll let u know asap